# How to manage database credentials for mule proejct

Tags: mule, database-connection, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I am using database connector component, with vault component to store the database credentials. Now as per the documentation of both components i have created different properties file for each environment to store the encrypted credentials for diff env.

Following is the structure of my mule project

[image]

Now the problem with this structure is that i have to build new deployable zip file whenever i have to update the database credentials for any environment.

I need a solution where i can keep all credentials encrypted and centralized and i don't have to create a build every time after updated the credentials, We can afford to restart the server, but building new zip and deploying is really cumbersome.

Second problem we have this approach is a developer needs to know the production db to update it in properties file, this is also a security issue.

Please suggest alternate approach for credentials management for mule projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend you do NOT try to change the secure solution provided to you by MuleSoft. To alleviate the need for packaging and deployment, you would have to extract the properties files outside of the deployment and this would be a huge risk. Regardless of where you store the property files within the deployment if you change the files, you have to package and re-deploy. I see the only solution to your problem as moving the files outside of the deployment and securely storing them. Mule has provided a solution while it may be cumbersome, they are securing these files first with encryption and secondly within the server container. You can move out the property files but you have to provide a custom implementation and you will be assuming great risk to your protected resources.

Comment: I have been looking around and have found this blog - http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-meets-zuul-centralized-properties-management-part-1/   also there is shared resources concept in mule should we consider this

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a VM arguement e.g. environment.type=local for local machine on your anypoint studio.
2. Read this variable in wherever you are reading your properties file in a way that environment type is read dynamically such as below.
   " location="classpath:properties/sample-app-${environment.type}.properties" doc:name="Secure Property Placeholder"/>
3. In order to set the environment type on your production server(or wherever you are using mule runtime), open \conf\wrapper.conf and add the arguement wrapper.java.additional.=-Dserver.type=production. If you already have any property in this file, you may need to set the value of n appropriately. For example 13 or 14.

This way you don't need to generate different deployment artefacts for different environment because correct properties file is picked by using environment specific VM arguement.